# Is it possible to loop over multiple lines of text with RegEx and wrap each line in some contextual HTML?

Tags: html, regex, scripting, loops, textmate

I've become rather comfortable using RegEx in little javascript apps/plugins of mine but right now I wish that RegEx could save me a whole lot of time by doing the following:

I have a long text file that is formatted in the following manner:

```
Area which can contain spaces
Address which contains spaces and special characters
Phone Number
(empty line)
Area... (repeats the same structure as above)
```

Here is a short excerpt:

```
Ponsonby
114 Ponsonby Rd Open Til 3Am Friday & Saturday
09 3786466

Queen St
291 Queen St (Next to Bor Ders)
09 3090660

Sylvia Park
Sylvia Park Shopping Complex (286 Mt Wellington Highway)
09 5730100
```

I know need to wrap this in the following:

```
<li class="item">
    <p class="phone">09 3786466</p>
    <div class="location">
        <strong>Ponsonby</strong>
        <p class="address">114 Ponsonby Rd Open Til 3Am Friday & Saturday</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

Is there any way I can run a RegEx to find each line info and the loop over my content wrapping things in this type of markup?

I am using TextMate by the way in case that matters.

So far my idea has been the following (which does not work):

```
([.\w\s]+)\n
([\w\s\b.]+)\n
([\d ]+)$\n
\n
```

And then in the replace part I would have my

```
<li class="item">
    <p class="phone">$3</p>
    <div class="location">
        <strong>$1</strong>
        <p>$2</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Jannis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tested function should do the trick:

```js
function process_data(text)
{ // HTML-ify some data
    var re = /(\S.*)\r?\n(\S.*)\r?\n([\d \-]+)(?=\r?\n[ ]*\r?\n|\s*$)/g;
    var rep_str = "<li class=\"item\">\n" +
        "    <p class=\"phone\">$3</p>\n" +
        "    <div class=\"location\">\n" +
        "        <strong>$1</strong>\n" +
        "        <p>$2</p>\n" +
        "    </div>\n" +
        "</li>\n";
    return text.replace(re, rep_str);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I am however having some issues actually getting it to run. Is there anything specific I need to do? I currently pass the text into the function but nothing gets rewritten… There is a quick example page here: http://treatme.dev.supply.net.nz/text.html

Comment: Actually, I just got it to work, the issue I was running into was that the `return` did not print the results into the element back, which makes sense now. A little tweak to the JS and it all worked great. Thanks a lot! As a little side note: I had to create a minimum HTML structure to run this as javascript, is there a way to just run this straight from within TextMate or another editor?

Comment: I actually use a simple test HTML page with a TEXTAREA input (which allows me to enter various strings) and a button which runs the Javascript test function and then writes out the results to a PRE element on the page. Quite handy.